# gstreamer rust get human readable output for bitrate set on x264enc

Tags: rust, gstreamer

Looking to get a human readable output of the bitrate and framerate for x264enc in rust bindings for confirming the change in value

Following the examples, it looks like bitrate is set from

> bitrate             : Bitrate in kbit/sec
>                           flags: readable, writable, changeable in NULL, READY, PAUSED or PLAYING state

so first we create the element and add it to the pipeline, then link it

```
 let myEnc = gst::ElementFactory::make("x264enc", None)
            .map_err(|_| MissingElement("x264enc"))?;
 //... do the .link() stuff
```

now to set the rate as gint

```
//... set the rate
 let setBitrate = 1500;
 let haveSetBr = myEnc.set_property("bitrate",&setBitrate).unwrap();
```

this generates an error telling us to change to `guint`, this seems to be `type guint = c_uint; => type c_uint = u32;` so change the type

```
  //... set the rate
 let setBitrate:u32 = 1500;
 let haveSetBr = myEnc.set_property("bitrate",&setBitrate).unwrap();
```

no error reported

```
//... get the rate
 let brNow = myEnc.get_property("bitrate");
            println!("the bit rate is set at {:#?}",brNow );
```

gives an output as an `enum`

```
the bit rate is set at Ok(
    Value(
        GString(
            Foreign(
                0x0000555555aebb00,
                4,
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

so how do you change the output type to a u32 number?

Now on to setting framerate as per the gst-inspect-1.0 x264enc, the capabilities report as

```
>  Capabilities:
>       video/x-raw
>               framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
>                   width: [ 16, 2147483647 ]
>                  height: [ 16, 2147483647 ]
>                  format: { (string)Y444, (string)Y42B, (string)I420, (string)YV12, (string)NV12, (string)Y444_10LE, (string)I422_10LE,
> (string)I420_10LE }
> 
>   SRC template: 'src'
>     Availability: Always
>     Capabilities:
>       video/x-h264
>               framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
>                   width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
>                  height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
>           stream-format: { (string)avc, (string)byte-stream }
>               alignment: au
>                 profile: { (string)high-4:4:4, (string)high-4:2:2, (string)high-10, (string)high, (string)main, (string)baseline,
> (string)constrained-baseline, (string)high-4:4:4-intra,
> (string)high-4:2:2-intra, (string)high-10-intra }
```

so following the example `glupload.rs` we add

```
 let caps = gst::Caps::builder("video/x-raw")
            .field("format", &gst_video::VideoFormat::I420.to_str())
            .field("framerate", &"25/1")
            .build();
 myEnc.set_caps(Some(&caps));
```

however this generates compile errors

```
error[E0599]: no method named `set_caps` found for struct `gst::Element` in the current scope
       --> examples....
        |
        |         myEnc.set_caps(Some(&caps));
        |              ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `gst::Element`
```

and here are the imports from the top of the script, are we missing any that would resolve the above error? for example do we need to link to another script in the examples folder or in the gstreamer/src/ folders?

```
extern crate gstreamer as gst;
use gst::gst_element_error;
use gst::prelude::*;
use glib::GString;
extern crate gstreamer_video as gst_video;
extern crate gstreamer_app as gst_app;
use std::env;
use anyhow::Error;
use derive_more::{Display, Error};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems here:

1. > so how do you change the output type to a u32 number?

The output of your application already tells you that this is a `glib::Value`, so the first step would be to check [it's docs](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/value/struct.Value.html): You need to get the value out of it, in your case via `value.get::<u32>()` or `value.get_some::<u32>()`.

2. > `myEnc.set_caps(Some(&caps));` however this generates compile errors

You can't just set caps on an element, that conceptually makes no sense and as the compiler tells you there is also no such function. If you want to enforce specific caps between pads of two elements you need to use a `capsfilter` element (set the caps on its `caps` property via [`set_property()`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/object/trait.ObjectExt.html#tymethod.set_property)) or by using [`element1.link_pads_filtered(Some("src"), &element2, Some("sink"), Some(&caps))`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/trait.ElementExt.html#tymethod.link_pads_filtered).

Comment: thanks Sebastian, for the pointers, I copied this from examples/src/bin/glupload.rs. On line 553 the `appsink.set_caps(Some(&caps));` seems to be set directly on appsink. Is this a special case as it has caps as a property where x264enc does not? So when an element has no caps, would you say performace wise it is better to use `link_pads_filtered` or insert a cpsfilter between two elements?

Comment: The `appsink` element has a `caps` property, which is a special case indeed.

Comment: For your other question, performance-wise it is exactly the same. `link_pads_filtered()` will add a `capsfilter` element with the given caps between the two elements.