# Print Element GString Property in Human Readable format

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I'm writing a `rust` application with a simple gstreamer pipeline.  I would like to print the stats property of the `appsink` element in a human readable format.

With this code:

```
let stats = appsink.get_property("stats").unwrap();
println!("stats: {:?}", stats);
```

I get:

```
stats: Value(GString(Foreign(0x7f9c008f00, 101)))
```

Since that isn't human readable, I tried:

```
let stats = appsink.get_property("stats").unwrap().get::<GString>();
println!("stats: {:?}", stats);
```

but got:

```
stats: Err(GetError { actual: GstStructure, requested: gchararray })
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the output.

---

I've looked at this post: [gstreamer rust get human readable output for bitrate set on x264enc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292703/gstreamer-rust-get-human-readable-output-for-bitrate-set-on-x264enc) but it doesn't show how to approach a `GString`.

Comment: What is this `stats` property? It's not in the [GStreamer docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/applib/gstappsink.html) nor when I do `gst-inspect-1.0 appsink`

Comment: I see it with `gst-inspect-1.0`, I am using a gstreamer built off of master, so maybe it is new.  It looks like it is part of GstBaseSink: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/base/gstbasesink.html?gi-language=c#gst_base_sink_get_stats

Comment: It is indeed pretty recent. According to your link, the `stats` property has type [`Structure`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/structure/struct.Structure.html). So something like this should work: `let stats = appsink.get_property("stats").unwrap().get::<Structure>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sort of reproduce this using the following example:

```
use gstreamer::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    gstreamer::init().unwrap();
    let source = gstreamer::ElementFactory::make("videotestsrc", Some("source")).expect("Could not create source element.");
    let val = source.get_property("pattern").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

This will attempt to get the `pattern` property on a generic VideoTestSrc element, and it will print out the string address instead of the actual string. Adding `.get::<GString>()` to the `let val` statement will produce a runtime error:

```
Err(GetError { actual: GstVideoTestSrcPattern, requested: gchararray })
```

which is telling us that it tried to cast to gchararray but the actual data type of the property is a custom type, GstVideoTestSrcPattern, which is not a string.  In your example, the property value has the type `GstStructure`.  It might be possible to use `.get::<GstVideoTestSrcPattern>()` to get the value of the `pattern` property and manipulate it as such, but since we want a string here, there's another way using the .transform() method defined on a glib::Value:

```
let val = source.get_property("pattern").unwrap().transform::<String>().unwrap().get::<String>().unwrap().unwrap();
```

This is rather unwieldy and it would be advised to do a lot more error checking on the values returned here (for example using the `?` operator instead of the `.unwrap()`s).

The `.transform::<String>()` call will try to give us a String representation of the property's value, but it gives us a `Option<Value>` which we must unwrap and convert into an actual String using `.get::<String>()`, which gives us a `Result<Option<String>, GetError>` (the inner option is because the string could be NULL).  Unwrapping those values gives us a printable string.

There might be a simpler way, but this at least gives you the result.  There is more documentation on how to deal with glib Value types here: https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/value/struct.Value.html
But unfortunately it's not very easy to read and doesn't have examples.  It might be possible to glean more info from the rust port of the gstreamer tutorials: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/tree/master/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Close to what transistor wrote, the correct way of doing this would be

```rust
let stats = appsink.get_property("stats").unwrap();
println!("stats: {:?}", stats.get::<gst::Structure>().expect("not a structure").expect("structure was None"));
```

You don't have to transform the `glib::Value` to a `String`, but you can directly get a `gst::Structure` from the `glib::Value` and work on that. Among other things it provides a `Debug` impl that allows direct printing of it, and various API for accessing the fields, etc. See https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/structure/struct.StructureRef.htm